# Ubuntu Server Terminating SSH Connection

Tags: networking, 20.04, ssh, openssh

I have an Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 that I want to SSH into. I am using the default ssh service on Ubuntu. I can connect with it and it works flawlessly, but after about 20 minutes, the connection terminates and leaves this message: Software caused connection abort. I thought that this is an odd case and tried to reconnect and the Ubuntu Server would refuse to connect. I would have to pull out the power and then turn it back on for it to connect for another 20 minutes. Can I fix this issue. When I ran a different OS on the machine, the ssh worked flawlessly.

EDIT: This is what `netstat -atunlp` looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The machine refusing to connect suggests that the sshd service crashed, or the OS crashed, or possibly the entire server shut down for some reason. If you have the ability to see what's going on physically with the server, or an IP-KVM/iDRAC, etc. that will give you a view of what's on the screen, you'll be able to see what happened specifically and go from there.

EDIT: If you can get to the console through one of the methods mentioned above, check the status of the SSH service (`sudo systemctl status sshd`), if it says active, then there's another issue going on (Likely firewall). If it says inactive or dead look over the logs posted below the status for some more information. Try starting it again (`sudo systemctl start sshd`), see if it starts successfully or errors out.

If it is started, and it's a firewall issue, check to see if UFW is running (`sudo ufw status`), if it's inactive, confirm your iptables (`iptables -L`), if it looks like this then it's not a firewall issue:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: I definitely know that the OS didn't crash, but I don't know how to find out what happened. Can you clarify what to do?

Comment: Updated the post for you.

Comment: I followed your steps and my sshd was active and had no errors. My UFW was disabled and by iptables look exactly the same as yours. What is wrong? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Is there any other possible firewall between you and the server that could be interfering with the connection?

Comment: I am connecting from a standard Windows 10 PC using MobaXTerm.

Comment: I even tried using the SSH Key but it still terminates and I can't reconnect to it.

Comment: I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ as the machine hosting the Ubuntu Server. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: What does the output of `netstat -atunlp` return?

Comment: I added an edit with the screenshot.

Comment: It's listening on port 22, so you shouldn't have any issue connecting. Try just using PuTTY and see if it works. If it doesn't, ensure you're either on the same internal network, or that there is port forwarding setup to ensure the connection will succeed